# backbone.js <button> click not firing

Tags: backbone.js

We have researched and tried all we could find but cannot see why button click even is not firing.  If we change the view render html color it shows the change, so view render is working okay but when the login button is clicked -> nothing.  No error shows in js console.  Tried with

`button#login_button` and `#login_button` and `login_button` - all nothing.  what are we missing?  thks for any help

```
  SessionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: ('#session'),
    initialize:function () {
        this.render();
    },
    render:function () {
      if (!session) {
        $(this.el).html(
          "<button id=\"login_button\" class=\"login_button black\">"+
          "Login"+
          "</button>");
        return this;
      } else {
        $(this.el).html(
          "<button id=\"logout_button\" class=\"login_button black\">"+
            "Logout</button>");
        return this; 
      }
    },
    events: {
        "click login_button" : "login",
        "click logout_button": "logout"
    },
    login: function(){
      alert("login");
      console.log("login dialog");
      //var loginView = new LoginView();
      //loginView.render().showModal();
    },
    logout: function(){
      alert("You Have Logged Out");
    }

  });
```

Comment: Though you said you tried with `#login_button` I kinda agree with lib3d, it should work. What could also be wrong: 1) the `el` you specify doesn't exist (I guess it's not the case) 2) some listener returns false or stops the propagation, therefore your callback ain't called. Also, `this.$el` = `$(this.el)`.

Comment: Do you have other elements on the page with the same id?  Try binding the event to the classes and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

You should keep '#' in selectors:

```
events: {
        "click #login_button" : "login",
        "click #logout_button": "logout"
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Do you wait for DOM ready to use `new` on this Backbone view class ?
The fact that your buttons are altered by the `html` calls means that you do.

As soon as you have checked that, you have to use `this.$el` instead of `$(this.el)`.

If it still does not work, search for event blocking and be sure ids are unique.

This very simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7XEr/1/) works with the same conditions you are telling us.

Comment: "*Tried with [...] `#login_button` [...] nothing.*"